# How to avoid license verification while developing?

Tags: android, android-lvl

yesterday I did integrated license verification library in my project, and now I can't continue with the developing because everytime I run the project the check fails because the app isn't downloaded from the play store, so the license is not valid.

Is there a way to prevent this? I mean some method than comment lines of code.

Thank you.

Comment: You haven't read docs, right? http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/setting-up.html#test-env

Comment: Sorry, the problem is that I'm not the publisher, and in the docs I read that only the publisher can test this.

Answer (score 1):

> I mean some method than comment lines of code.

You can e.g. use a `static final` variable set to a constant value and an `if` which compares this with a constant value. Due to the keyword `final`, the result of this condition test can't change. Thus, at compile time the unreachable code is not included in the compiler output.

Example:

```
static final boolean DEVELOP = false; // For developing set this to true

if ( DEVELOP == false ) {
    Log.i("", "This will be included and executed");
} else {
    Log.i("", "This code is unreachable and will not be included");
}
```

E.g. in Eclipse you will notice that you get warnings due to unreachable or "dead" code (which I find very helpful to see that the passages I wanted to are included/excluded).